# If else statement bash script

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm not sure why my script is always executing the last statment else even if the files file1 and file2 are not empty :

```
SERVER_NAME=$HOSTNAME
SENDER="Admin"
SUBJECT="Notification from "$SERVER_NAME""
RECEIVER="admin@mycompany.com"
file1=/home/first_file.txt 
file2=/home/second_file.txt
TEXT1="The file $file1 is empty"
TEXT2="The file $file2 is empty"
TEXT3="Both files are empty"


if [ -s $file1 && -s $file2 ]
     then
        echo "files are good"  

    elif [[ -s $file1 ]]
     then
        echo -e "$TEXT2" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$RECEIVER" &>/dev/null

    elif [[ -s $file2 ]]
    then
        echo -e "$TEXT1" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$RECEIVER"  &>/dev/null

    else
        echo -e "$TEXT3" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$RECEIVER"  &>/dev/null

    fi
```

The requirement is to send a notification if one or both files are empty

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please try to print the values of variables before if conditions to make sure their values are not null.

Comment: @Inder There is no word-splitting of parameter expansions inside `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: There's no evidence in the question that the two files *aren't* empty, other than your claim that they aren't, or that `$file1` and `$file2` expand to the names you think they do.

Comment: You use `$file1` when declaring `TEXT1` before `file1` is declared.

Comment: Does your script have DOS line endings? If so, then `file1` really has the value `/home/first_file.txt\r`, not `/home/first_file.txt`.

Comment: Script updated. but still doing the same

@chepner the script was initially created in Centos using VIM, it's not coming from any MS machine.

Comment: What's the output of `printf '%q\n' "$file1"`?

Comment: And the output of `ls -l "$file1" "$file2"`?

Comment: `printf '%q\n' "$file1"
printf '%q\n' "$file2"
ls -l "$file1" "$file2"`

`/home/first_file.txt
/home/second_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 15 août  12:06 /home/first_file.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 15 août  12:06 /home/second_file.txt`

Comment: The files are both empty...

Comment: @john Sorry, I have changed the files for testing purposes. It works now after changing `if [ -s $file1 && -s $file2 ]`  To `if [[ -s $file1 && -s $file2 ]]`  not sure if this was the error

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. `&&` doesn't work with single brackets. You'd have to write `if [ -s "$file1" ] && [ -s "$file2" ]` or `if [ -s "$file1" -a -s "$file2" ]` instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a working script for reference.

```
SERVER_NAME=$HOSTNAME
SENDER="Admin"
SUBJECT="Notification from "$SERVER_NAME""
RECEIVER="admin@mycompany.com"
file1=/home/first_file.txt 
file2=/home/second_file.txt
TEXT1="The file $file1 is empty"
TEXT2="The file $file2 is empty"
TEXT3="Both files are empty"


if [[ -s $file1 && -s $file2 ]]
     then
        echo "files are good"  

    elif [[ -s $file1 ]]
     then
        echo -e "$TEXT2" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$RECEIVER" &>/dev/null

    elif [[ -s $file2 ]]
    then
        echo -e "$TEXT1" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$RECEIVER"  &>/dev/null

    else
        echo -e "$TEXT3" | mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$RECEIVER"  &>/dev/null

    fi
```